# Apache Redirect Dynamic Url to Static. Dynamic string shows in target URL

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

Trying to set up a few redirects that look something like this :

From
http://sub.example.com/foo/foo.php?letter=Al&last=40
To
https://www.example.com/foo/bar

When I run the source URL in the browser apache redirects me to
https://www.example.com/?letter=Al&last=40  instead of https://www.example.com/foo/bar

This is what I have in the virtualhost.conf

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^letter=Al&last=40$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/foo/bar? [R=301,L]
```

Everything I've read through so far confirms that this should work.

PS: this is for Apache Server version: Apache/2.4.18

Answer (score 0):

You need the [QSD](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag to avoid copying the query strings.